# Using iteritools groupby to group a list of paths, by date

Tags: python

```
tabela path --SAME AS BELOW
tabela_path2 = array[[[],[]]]

    needle = []
    for x in range(2015, 2090):
        needle.append(str(x))

    for needleIndex in range(len(needle)):
        for hayIndex in range(len(tabela_path)):
            if needle[needleIndex] in str(tabela_path[hayIndex]):
                #tabela_path2 somehow fill the table as shown below in tables, 
                #comment says I can use iteritools.groupby
```

desired output
paths rearanged in as many columns as there are years
This is supposed to be table path 2

| 'C: ... 2020_06_19 | 'C: ...2021_07_01 | 'C: ... 2022_05_12 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C: ... 2020_06_19... | 'C: ...2021_07_01 | 'C: ... 2022_05_12 ... |
| C: ... 2020_06_19.... | 'C: ...2021_07_01 | 'C:2022_05_12 |
| C: ... 2020_06_19.... | 'C: ...2021_07_01 | 'C:2022_05_12 |
| ALL ITEMS WITH 2020 Date | ALL ITEMS WITH 2021 Date | ALL ITEMS WITH 2022 Date |

more columns if there were more years in data

```
from itertools import groupby
import string
import random

tabela_path = ['C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_hor_BBHA9120J', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_ver_BBHA9120J', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_hor_BBHA9120J\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_hor_BBHA9120J\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_hor_BBHA9120J\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_hor_BBHA9120J\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_ver_BBHA9120J\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_ver_BBHA9120J\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_ver_BBHA9120J\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_ver_BBHA9120J\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Hor_BBHA9120J_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Ver_BBHA9120J_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_hor_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_ver_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver_new_Mount\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver_new_Mount\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver_new_Mount\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver_new_Mount\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Hor_BBHA9120J_new_Mount\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Hor_BBHA9120J_new_Mount\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Hor_BBHA9120J_new_Mount\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Hor_BBHA9120J_new_Mount\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Ver_BBHA9120J_new_Mount\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Ver_BBHA9120J_new_Mount\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Ver_BBHA9120J_new_Mount\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Ver_BBHA9120J_new_Mount\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134_new_Mount\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134_new_Mount\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134_new_Mount\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134_new_Mount\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_hor_new_Mount\\System', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_ver_new_Mount\\Graphics', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_ver_new_Mount\\Report Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_ver_new_Mount\\Setups', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_ver_new_Mount\\System']

tabela_path = sorted (tabela_path)

#print(tabela_path)
for key, group in (groupby(tabela_path, key = )):
    print("                                                              ")
    print ('key:',key,' group:', list (group))
```

Comment: This seems like a worse way to essentially just `itertools.groupby`

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use `np.array`, either.

Comment: how do i use iteritools groupby to fix my problem

Comment: Read the documentation & try to use it.  Come back if you get stuck.

Comment: the groupby creates a new group for every path

Comment: no idea how to group by path (year)

Comment: Please answer, this is my first project ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with your code so I rewrote what I think you're trying to do completely. I would recommend using RegEx instead of finding in string as the code is much more flexible if you want to modify it to group by something else than year. It also avoids making an array of all years and then looping through all the years, instead it just extracts the year from the path.

```
import itertools
import re
import pprint

calibration_paths = ['C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19', ... ]

def extract_year(path: string):
    year = re.search(r'\\\d+_', path)
    return year.group(0)[1:5]

paths_by_year={}

for key, group in itertools.groupby(calibration_paths , extract_year):
    paths_by_year[key] = list(group)
```